# Command to find out if a Perl value is initialized

Tags: arrays, perl, groovy, initialization, ternary-operator

My question right now is based around a problem I'm having with CSV documents but it is also more general.

I'm looking to use something like the null question mark in Java/Groovy/Gosu to determine if an array index has been initialized.

I have something like:

```
for ( my i = 0; i < @engVals or i < @frenchVals; i++ ) {

    $csv->print($file, [ $engVals[i] ?: "",  , $frenchVals[i] ?: "" ] );

    # Where Elvis ops ensure that the array element at i is initialized, and if not stores blank in the CSV
}
```

Comment: You want to know if something is [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
defined $engVals[i]
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html

Or you can do

```
$engVals[i] // ''
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or

Comment: Note: versions of perl earlier than 5.10 do not have the `//` operator.

Answer (score 3):

You need the *defined or* operator `//` which returns its left operand if it is defined, otherwise its right operand

```
$csv->print($file, [ $engVals[i] // "", $frenchVals[i] // "" ] );
```

I was unsure why you had two commas between the two array elements. If that was a a typo then the above statement is what you want, but if you intended that there should be an intermediate blank field in the resulting CSV data then you should write `, "",`.

Comment: Thank you, sorry the coma in the middle was to give an extra blank space to separate the two columns in the csv.